# Login is disabled and the password is incorrect for user sa

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to write an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with a SQL Server on Mac in Docker [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIy8S.png). Then I initialize SQL Server in Docker container.

Tables are successfully created. But I can't connect to my database from my project. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpioK.png)

Here is my appsettings file: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu5Je.png)

I tried to change passwords, tried command system prune to clean mounted data, but the problem persists.

Comment: Please paste text-based things into your questions as text (in code fences or quotation blocks as necessary) rather than screen shots. Screen shots are not indexable nor searchable, so they don't help anybody else that may be experiencing similar problems.

Comment: There's no evidence of how you configure the sa password for your SQL Server container named `db`. So what's in your `./db/Dockerfile`? Also be aware that the sa password is only configured at initial container creation, so if you change the password in your `Dockerfile` it won't affect the container until you delete it and recreate it - and doing so will probably lose all of your system databases and user databases if you haven't setup volumes properly.

Comment: Did you have the chance to check that in local, I mean other than docker? Is it working as expected on local environment?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron On local environment i am starting container with `docker run -d --name Microservices -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Administrator0000%' -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`.It was working successfully.Than i applied my migrations and tables generated also successfully.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I changed connection string in my apsettings file for this `Server=db;Database=Microservices;User Id=sa;Password=Administrator0000%;Trusted_Connection=True`.Problem with password disappeared but there is different problem `authentification exited with code 139`.So, my container exits with this code.`The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.` this message appear after my exited container

Comment: @AlwaysLearning https://github.com/tometchy/Docker-compose-dotnet-core-and-mssql.git I used this github to create docker file for db and also for initialising